# How to get html element by Id passed from ng-init of angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I could get the element of html by id when i use ng-click, but with ng-init I get null. please check my pen http://codepen.io/solidet/pen/pbJMjq

**html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var memId = "bb7de28f-0f89-4f14-8575-d494203acec7";
</script>   

<div  ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="getMember(memId)">
    <span id="audio-{{memId}}">
        Your mem ID: {{memId}}
    </span>     
    <span ng-click="getMember(memId)"> click me <span>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.memId = $window.memId;

  $scope.getMember = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    var voice = document.getElementById('audio-'+ id);
    console.log(voice);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: First of all you probably should close some tags correctly in your HTML.

Comment: just close the span tag

Comment: this won't work the way you want, because `ng-init` happens before the HTML is rendered, and you are calling a function that is looking for rendered HTML.  This isn't the appropriate use for `ng-init` anyway.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit "This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`..."

Comment: ng-init + document.getElementById = 2 angular bad practices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could get it via angular  $timeout  which is wait until angular cycle finshed and elements rendered

**controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', '$timeout', function($scope, $window, $timeout) {
    $scope.memId = $window.memId;
    $scope.getMember = function(id) {

        $timeout(function() {
            console.log(document.querySelector('#audio-' + id))
        });
    };

}]);
```

Comment: This is not a good approach at all: What if the browser is slow rendering due to other processes? You cannot rely on on a timeout

Comment: @sailens this is not a `setTimeout` this is `$timeout` by angular fires after angular digest not after browser frame  and not related to browser speed!!

Comment: True. I was reviewing vanilla javascript before that I my mind got stuck there. My apologies

Answer (score 0):

You can't access DOM elements in `ng-init` since they're not yet added to the DOM at this point. Directly accessing DOM elements in angular is frowned upon to anyways so maybe rethink your code design.

---

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit for appropriate uses of that directive.

> There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`, such as for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.